# Separate an Object from its parent after pushing it to an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a form for my blog. The blog is an object with numerous content objects inside of it.
I think I am not thinking clearly because the content I push to the Array keeps its reactivity to the parent even though its not a ref or anything like that.

Here is the Vue Component:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

const blog = ref({
    link: 'Link',
    category: 'category',
    title: 'title',
    image: 'Image',
    body: 'Body',
    content: [] as any[]
})

let contentItem = {
    parent: 'parent',
    title: 'title',
    image: 'Image',
    code: 'Code',
    body: 'Body',
}

// Add Content Item
function addContent(content: any) {
    const item = content
    blog.value.content.push(item)
} 

</script>


<template>
<div class="flex p-8 text-slate-600 w-full flex-col gap-4 rounded">
            <h4 class="font-bold text-red-50">Blog Content</h4>
            <input type="text" v-model="contentItem.parent">
            <input type="text" v-model="contentItem.title">
            <input type="text" v-model="contentItem.image">
            <textarea class="w-full h-[200px]" type="text" v-model="contentItem.code"> {{ contentItem.code }} </textarea>
            <textarea class="w-full h-[200px]" type="text" v-model="contentItem.body"> {{ contentItem.body }} </textarea>
            <button class="p-4 w-1/2 bg-slate-50" type="button" @click="addContent(contentItem)">Add Content</button>
        </div>
</template>
```

`

I have tried using "readonly", I tried passing the value to another object (as you see in the current code) and I just don't understand why it can pass a new object, but there all the same object.
I know the solutions going to be simple, but I looked and all I kept finding is people wanting to keep the reactivity in an array (opposite of my problem).

Comment: You could try `const item = { ...content }`

Answer (score 2):

Try to push object by value not by reference:

```js
const { ref, computed, onMounted } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const blog = ref({
      link: 'Link',
      category: 'category',
      title: 'title',
      image: 'Image',
      body: 'Body',
      content: []
    })

    let contentItem = ref({
      parent: 'parent',
      title: 'title',
      image: 'Image',
      code: 'Code',
      body: 'Body',
    })

    function addContent(content) {
      blog.value.content.push({...content})
    } 

    return {
      addContent,
      contentItem,
      blog
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div class="flex p-8 text-slate-600 w-full flex-col gap-4 rounded">
    <h4 class="font-bold text-red-50">Blog Content</h4>
    <input type="text" v-model="contentItem.parent">
    <input type="text" v-model="contentItem.title">
    <input type="text" v-model="contentItem.image">
    <textarea class="w-full h-[200px]" type="text" v-model="contentItem.code"> {{ contentItem.code }} </textarea>
    <textarea class="w-full h-[200px]" type="text" v-model="contentItem.body"> {{ contentItem.body }} </textarea>
    <button class="p-4 w-1/2 bg-slate-50" type="button" @click="addContent(contentItem)">Add Content</button>
  </div>
  {{blog}}
</div>
```